# Problem printing central european characters in Vim

Tags: vim

Here's the problem in a nutshell.

I wrote a text file which I need to print out (in a hurry) that contains central european characters (šđčćž/ŠĐČĆŽ).

Vim's encoding settings are as folows;
set encoding=cp1250
set fileencoding=

Upon printing out comes garbage. What should be changed to fix that?

*Really hate Vim's frekin' 1001 options in a time like this. Can't it do a simple thing and just print what's on screen?!*

Answer (score 3):

Check the option `printencoding`.

The help says it's empty by default, and when the encoding is multi-byte Vim tries to convert them to the `printencoding`. Plus, if it's empty "the conversion will be to latin1". This is what may be causing the trouble.

I'd like to ask: why not to use UTF-8?

Comment: CE characters in cp1250 are not multibyte, as far as I understood it. I don't seem to have printencoding option available (version with +printer, but not postscript)

Comment: Why not utf-8? Don't know ... always did it like this, always worked before.

Comment: @Rook: Hmm, without `printencoding` I really don't know what may be causing this problem... maybe you can print with another editor to save some time now that you're in a hurry. Regarding UTF-8, I prefer to use it as solves many problems. It support (almost) every writing system, and is backward compatible with ASCII. Also, no need to a byte order mark and these other things.

Comment: @sidyll - Do you know of an easy way in Vim to change cp1250 to utf-8? (I prefer to do it from Vim since I have page feeds there which not many editors support).

Comment: @sidyll - that just screws up the whole thing.

Comment: @sisyll - never mind anymore. I can't check this in anymore this week. My opinion of vim at this moment is that visual studio will be replacing it very soon, regardless of its famous "usability" (for what?)...

Comment: @Rook, ouch, I saw your other question and while doing it here I encountered the same behaviour.